# FirePHP headers not working with nginx and FPM

Tags: php, nginx, firephp

I have the FirePHP FireFox extionsion installed and it appears to be working. I also have take the sample code to test, but I am not getting a response.

```
<?php
require('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
ob_start();

$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
$var = array('i'=>10, 'j'=>20);
$firephp->log($var, 'Iterators');
```

I don't see any extra headers in the Firebug NET tab - so I'm wondering if there are special instructions for configuring FirePHP when using PHP FPM or through Nginx.

> PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2

### Update: Server Response Headers

```
Server      nginx/1.0.5
Date        Mon, 19 Dec 2011 19:12:16 GMT
Content-Type    text/html
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection      keep-alive
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3
Content-Encoding    gzip
Request Headersview source
Host        localhost
```

Comment: Have you checked out this link?   http://serverfault.com/a/201851

Comment: @BradFJacobs, thanks I just added those lines and restarted but no dice. I also am not having any errors or 502 messages like mentioned there.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: And are you sure it is not FireFox/FirePHP query fault? Can you see modified `User-Agent` header in your XHR or additional `X-FirePHP-Version` header?

Comment: Can you set headers in php and see them in the firebug response? 

If you can't then something is wrong with your nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can find troubleshooting instructions for a FirePHP setup here: http://sourcemint.com/github.com/firephp/firephp/1/-docs/Troubleshooting

You need to make sure FirePHP identifies itself in the request headers which will only happen when the Firebug Console and Net panels are enabled.

I am assuming FirePHP is identifying itself.

With a proxy such as nginx involved problems may arise if headers are not being forwarded as-is. Nginx will fail if FirePHP sends too much data in the headers. This limit can be [increased via nginx configuration](http://shikii.net/blog/firephp-on-nginx-502-bad-gateway/). This should not be a problem with the little data you are sending in the example though.

Short from going through nginx debug logs you could try [FirePHP 1.0 + DeveoperCompanion](http://sourcemint.com/github.com/firephp/firephp/1/-docs/Clients#devcomp) which sends a secondary request to fetch the data vs sending all data in headers.

Comment: I added the headers from the PHP script I used. As you can see there is no mention of FirePHP which makes me think that PHP-FPM or nginx are ignoring or overwriting the response headers. I have the firebug net and console panels working (which is where I got these).

Comment: Do you see FirePHP identifying itself in the `User-Agent` or `X-FirePHP-Version` **request** header?